# Сохранить результат выбора пользователя в куки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Условно говоря есть следующий код:

```
<head>
    <link id="mystyle" rel="stylesheet" href="black.css" />
</head>
```

По нажатию на кнопку я запускаю обработчик:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("mystyle").href="red.css";
</script>
```

У меня меняется CSS файл с оформлением на сайте. Как можно записать в Cokies данную информацию, чтобы браузер запомнил какой файл используется? Желательно на JS. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Вам нужно это значение на сервере? Как долго оно должно храниться?

Comment: А с чем именно проблема у вас? Вы не знаете, как записать в куки?

Comment: @mego4iter я хочу записать это в куки браузера пользователя через js, достаточно чтобы хранилось буквально 24 часа

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, да, раньше никогда не работал с куками, почитал статью по поводу работы на сайте лерн яваскрипт, но не дошло)

Comment: Там даже готовая функция есть для работы с куками - https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie#setcookie-name-value-options

Comment: Нужно не файл запомнить а значение переменной и не обязательно в куки, можно в  localstorage или sessionstorage, и проверять наличие и значение переменной. Еще если это темы оформления и там цвета только меняются, то можно через css переменные менять элементы темы, или к body просто добавлять класс-идентификатор темы - т.е. запоминаем тему в переменную, и потом проверяем